# Timeouts with lots of MQTT connections to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: performance, activemq-artemis

I am working on configuring an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster to serve around 100k connections. My cluster involves 6 brokers with config copied below. All brokers are running on dedicated VM (14cpu, 20GB memory).

I am evaluating HiveMQ enterprise and ActiveMQ Artemis to find out which one suits our expectations. [HiveMQ Swarm](https://docs.hivemq.com/hivemq-swarm/latest/index.html) is being used to create connections to broker cluster. I am getting around 50k connections in 8 minutes, which is very low than my expectation and also compared to HiveMQ. What can be changed in order to make cluster more performant? On client side error message is "connection timed out" while on broker side logs have error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMQ850000: Unable to store MQTT state within given timeout: 5000ms
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTStateManager.storeSessionState(MQTTStateManager.java:177) ~[artemis-mqtt-protocol-2.31.0.jar:2.31.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTSubscriptionManager.removeSubscriptions(MQTTSubscriptionManager.java:291) ~[artemis-mqtt-protocol-2.31.0.jar:2.31.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTSubscriptionManager.clean(MQTTSubscriptionManager.java:368) ~[artemis-mqtt-protocol-2.31.0.jar:2.31.0]
```

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>

      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- It is recommended to keep this value as 1, maximizing the number of records stored about redeliveries.
           However if you must preserve state of individual redeliveries, you may increase this value or set it to -1 (infinite). -->
      <max-redelivery-records>1</max-redelivery-records>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      
      <!-- if you want to retain your journal uncomment this following configuration.

      This will allow your system to keep 7 days of your data, up to 10G. Tweak it accordingly to your use case and capacity.

      it is recommended to use a separate storage unit from the journal for performance considerations.

      <journal-retention-directory period="7" unit="DAYS" storage-limit="10G">data/retention</journal-retention-directory>

      You can also enable retention by using the argument journal-retention on the `artemis create` command -->

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
       <!--<thread-pool-max-size>40</thread-pool-max-size>-->

      <journal-device-block-size>8192</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>100M</journal-file-size>
      
      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 19.23 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 52000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>52000</journal-buffer-timeout>

      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->

      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      
      <page-sync-timeout>288000</page-sync-timeout>

      <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit. This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

      The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
      You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

      <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size> -->

      <!-- the maximum number of messages accepted before entering full address mode.
           if global-max-size is specified the full address mode will be specified by whatever hits it first. -->
      <global-max-messages>-1</global-max-messages>

      <acceptors>
         <!-- useEpoll means: it will use Netty epoll if you are on a system (Linux) that supports it -->
         <!-- amqpCredits: The number of credits sent to AMQP producers -->
         <!-- amqpLowCredits: The server will send the # credits specified at amqpCredits at this low mark -->
         <!-- amqpDuplicateDetection: If you are not using duplicate detection, set this to false
                                      as duplicate detection requires applicationProperties to be parsed on the server. -->
         <!-- amqpMinLargeMessageSize: Determines how many bytes are considered large, so we start using files to hold their data.
                                       default: 102400, -1 would mean to disable large message control -->

         <!-- Note: If an acceptor needs to be compatible with HornetQ and/or Artemis 1.x clients add
                    "anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic." to the acceptor url.
                    See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1644 for more information. -->
         <acceptor name= "artemis">tcp://172.28.104.100:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;serverKeepAlive=-1;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLrnalManagementObjects=false</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
      </acceptors>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>

            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
            <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>

            <!-- The size of each page file -->
            <page-size-bytes>10M</page-size-bytes>

            <!-- When we start applying the address-full-policy, e.g paging -->
            <!-- Both are disabled by default, which means we will use the global-max-size/global-max-messages  -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>

            <!-- When we read from paging into queues (memory) -->

            <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>
            <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>

            <!-- Limit on paging capacity before starting to throw errors -->

            <page-limit-bytes>-1</page-limit-bytes>
            <page-limit-messages>-1</page-limit-messages>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
      
      <connectors>
         <connector name="artemis">tcp://172.28.104.100:61616</connector>
      </connectors>
      
      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="gss-broadcast">
            <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>100</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
         </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>

      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="gss-discovery"> 
            <group-address>${udp-address:231.7.7.7}</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <ha-policy>
         <replication>
            <master>
               <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
            </master>
         </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <cluster-user>cluster-user</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>cluster</cluster-password>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="gss-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>         
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <!--address>jms</address>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>-->
            <!--<static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors> -->
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="gss-discovery"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>

      <metrics>
         <jvm-memory>true</jvm-memory> <!-- defaults to true -->
         <jvm-gc>true</jvm-gc> <!-- defaults to false -->
         <jvm-threads>true</jvm-threads> <!-- defaults to false -->
         <file-descriptors>true</file-descriptors> <!-- defaults to false -->
         <processor>true</processor> <!-- defaults to false -->
         <uptime>true</uptime> <!-- defaults to false -->
         <plugin class-name="com.redhat.amq.broker.core.server.metrics.plugins.ArtemisPrometheusMetricsPlugin"/>
      </metrics>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to increase JVM thread pool size, max memory, and min memory.

Comment: How fast is the storage layer that the broker is using? In order to support persistent sessions some state has to be written to disk on every connection. If your storage mechanism is slow then it will start to bottleneck.

Comment: It is AFF Netapp, all flash array with SSD drives. I don't think storage is a problem.

Comment: When the broker is created it performs a load calculation on the disk to determine the value for `journal-buffer-timeout` in `broker.xml`. As noted in the related comment, "Your system could perform 19.23 writes per millisecond." This isn't terribly fast. The SSD on my laptop can support _250_ writes per millisecond - an order of magnitude more. It's possible that there was some activity on your disk when the calculation was made so you can recalculate it using the `bin/artemis perf-journal` command and modifying `broker.xml` with the new value.

Comment: Is there any recommended value? After I run command, I get suggestions to change journal-buffer-timeout.

Auto tuning journal ...
Performing 5 tests writing 250 blocks of 4096 on each test, sync=true with journalType = ASYNCIO
Your system can execute 22.73 syncs per millisecond
Your journal-buffer-timeout should be:44000
You should use this following configuration:

<journal-buffer-timeout>44000</journal-buffer-timeout>

Comment: The recommended value is what the `perf-journal` command provides to you.

Comment: is there any other change which can be made to improve performance?  I am new to Artemis.

Comment: One thing you could do to confirm that the disk is the bottleneck is to set `<persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>` and run the connection test again. Also, you could disable durable state management by adding this to the `<addresses>` block in `broker.xml`: `<address name="$sys.mqtt.sessions"><anycast><queue name="$sys.mqtt.sessions"><durable>false</durable></queue></anycast></address>`. If durable state is disabled it means that MQTT subscribers will have to re-subscribe when they reconnect after a broker restart rather than having their subscriptions automatically restored.

Comment: I am also going to inspect the code to see if there are any optimizations which could be made.

Comment: We are seeing much better performance with the changes you suggested. Is this something we can use in Production?

Comment: Which exact change did you make?

Comment: I set <persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled> and added <address name="$sys.mqtt.sessions"><anycast><queue name="$sys.mqtt.sessions"> to addresses block.

Comment: I doubt you'd want to disable persistence entirely in production as that means no messages would survive a broker restart, but there are use-cases where that's viable. I'll add answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support persistent sessions (which is part of the MQTT specification) some state is written to disk on every connection. If your storage mechanism is slow then it can bottleneck.

You can disable this functionality by adding this to the `<addresses>` block in `broker.xml`:

```xml
<address name="$sys.mqtt.sessions">
   <anycast>
      <queue name="$sys.mqtt.sessions">
         <durable>false</durable>
      </queue>
   </anycast>
</address>
```

This will increase performance, but it means that existing MQTT subscribers will have to *re-subscribe* when they reconnect after a broker restart rather than having their subscriptions automatically restored. This may be perfectly fine for you use-case (e.g. using clean sessions) or it may cause problems if the clients expect the subscriptions to be automatically restored on reconnect.

You can also disable persistence completely using this:

```xml
<persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>
```

However, this is generally not recommended as it means **no messages will survive a broker restart**.

It's worth noting that your disk seems slow based on the calculated `journal-buffer-timeout`. When the broker is created it performs a load calculation on the disk to determine the value for `journal-buffer-timeout` in `broker.xml`. As noted in the related comment:

> Your system could perform 19.23 writes per millisecond.

The SSD on my laptop can support *250* writes per millisecond - an order of magnitude more. It's possible that there was some activity on your disk when the calculation was made so you can recalculate it using the `bin/artemis perf-journal` command and modifying `broker.xml` with the new value. However, if the new value isn't significantly larger than the old value then it won't make much difference.

Comment: In this scenario would it be feasible to add more small size brokers to cluster instead of having 5 large size brokers?  What is impact of horizontal scaling?

Comment: [This documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html#performance-considerations) may answer that question for you. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks :). I have something to think about over weekend. Is there any certain metrics I should look at? I am not sure how to start or answer "Do I have enough clients so that each node in the cluster has sufficient consumers to receive all the messages produced on that node? If the answer to that question is "yes" then clustering may, in fact, improve overall message throughput for you. If the answer to that question is "no" then you’re likely to get better performance from either a smaller cluster or just a single broker." Clients would increase gradually.

Comment: There are metrics available on the ClusterControl. The higher those metrics the more often messages are being distributed from one cluster node to another which will tend to decrease overall throughput. Ultimately, though, you'll want to measure the performance of your actual application(s) with an expected production load similar to what's described in the documentation.